# Why isn’t the else in my if-statement not returning the correct outputs?

Tags: computer-science, code.org

I am working on coding in my Computer Science class and my function isn’t working correctly. I rewrote my code to make an example:

```
function getWords(userWord) {
  var returnList = [];
  var wordList = [blue, red,     purple];  

  for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    if (userWorld == wordList[i]) {
      appendItem(returnList, wordList[i]);
      return returnList[];
    } else {
      return “Not Found.”;
    }
  }
}
```

I try this and it will only return “Not Found.” even if the word matches.

Comment: Which language are you using? Is this the correct code, there are some typos (like `userWorld` vs `userWord`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, I solved your issue. :)

You had some misspelling, and some errors in your code.

See, the problem is that `return` keyword stops the execution of your `for` loop once a condition is met. In your case, both `if` and `else` have `return` keyword in them, so your `for` loop will never execute more then once.

In other words, your `if` statement will work only if you put word 'blue'.

If you were to put word 'red', which is the second element in your array, you would obviously go into `else` statement, because variable `i` would be 0 (AKA 'blue' in your array). By going in `else` it will return 'Not found.' and it would stop the for loop completely.

Hope you understand now :)

Anyways, here is your solution friend, let me know if it works, or if you have any questions :

```
let word = 'purple';

function getWords(userWord) {

var returnList = [];

var wordList = ['blue', 'red', 'purple'];  

let boolCheck = false;

for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {

    if(userWord == wordList[i]){

        boolCheck = true;

        returnList.push(wordList[i]);

    }

}

if(boolCheck){

    return returnList;

}

else{

    return "Not found.";

}

  }


let wordGet = getWords(word);

console.log(wordGet);
```